# How to calculate the probabilty of obtaining a complete matching of elements from 3 sets, when all subsets are picked at random.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, recreational-mathematics

I have 3 sets of 15 elements, sets A B and C. Each element in set A matches with one and only one element in set B, and one and only one element in set C. For example there are 15 distinct colours in set A, and the same 15 colours in set B and C.

One picks an element from set A, then set B, and finally set C, which forms a group (group number 1). This will then repeat until all the elements have been grouped. I want to calculate the probability of there being at least one matching group of elements 'correct' (all 3 colours are the same) when all 15 groups have been made by picking the elements at random from their respective sets (still only one element from each set).

Sorry about the lackluster delivery of the question, I find it very hard to phrase.

Comment: When you have only 2 sets, let's say $A$ and $B$, then this is the derangement problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement). You can adapt the technique for counting derangements to this problem.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding this, but how is a group supposed to consist of elements of only one color, if all elements from B have a color (call it "*b*") and all elements of C have a different color ("*c*")?

Comment: @jpvee There are 15 distinct colours in set A (call them 1 2 3 4 5....15) and the same colours in B and C. That is in set B there is (1 2 3 4 5....15) and also the same in set C. A group consists of a colour from each of the sets (E.G 1 2 3 or 1 1 2 or  1 15 1 - 1 1 1 is an example of a group that is 'correct')

Answer (score 1):

Arrange  $15$ elements in a row, say $1,2,3,.......15$, and we need to arrange two more rows of $15$

We shall select sets of $3$ from *columns* formed along with the other two rows.

If **no** set of three has to match, one from rows $2$ and $3$  need to be deranged w.r.t. row $1$.

Denoting the number of [derangements](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Derangement.html) of $n$ objects by $D_n$, a simple formula is $D_n = \left[\dfrac{n!}{e}\right],$
where $[x]$ is the nearest integer function, e.g. $D_4 = [\frac{4!}{e}] = 9$

So # of ways in which no column is identical $= (D_{15})\cdot15!$ against a total of $(15!)^2$  arrangements,

and using the complement, P(at least one column has the same colors) $= 1 - \dfrac{(D_{15})\cdot15!}{(15!)^2} =1 -\dfrac{(D_{15})}{(15!)}  $

---

*Added*

[Wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+-+!15%2F15!) gives the numerical value as $\approx 0.6321$

Comment: You said "If no set of three has to match, one from rows 2 and 3 need to be deranged w.r.t. row 1.", but only the one from rows 2 OR 3 need to be deranged w.r.t. row 1, as then the set is no longer perfect. Not sure if that changes the answer because i'm still comprehending it, but thank you!!

Comment: I just wrote it in English, what I meant was that $2\; XOR\; 3$ being different from $1$ is a necessary and sufficient condition. Of course, both could also be different from $1$

Comment: How come the # of ways in which no column is identical is (D15) * 15! ? Where does the 15! come from? Surely the overall chance of having a column with 3 elements all matching is different from the chance of having a column with 2 elements matching? Imagine I had 100 elements in each column, surely the chance would lower, since I need 100 elements to match up perfectly as opposed to just 2, since one 'bad element' ruins the whole set.

Comment: If, say, row 2 is totally mismatching with row 1 (i.e. deranged), whichever of 15! arrangements are used for row 3, no column will match.  We are computing P(at least one column matches) = 1 - P(no column matches)